# How to run multiple services on a EC2 container instance and have Healthy Targets for Health Checks?

Tags: terraform, amazon-elb

I have an unusual problem (perhaps an easy solution but I tried a few ways without success).

I have 2 tasks running on a EC2 container instance in an ECS cluster. 

`Task 1 is a DAEMON exposing port X
Task 2 is an application exposing port Y`

They both are running. When I check the Health check status for the EC2 instance, it shows 2 entries for it. 

`Entry 1 is Healthy for the DAEMON health check port at port X
Entry 2 is Draining for the Application health check port at port Y`

I would like a single entry (`for the application health check port Y`) for the EC2 instance and a Healthy state for it.

How can I accomplish this with the 2 tasks running on it. Should I not be exposing the Health Check port for the DAEMON task ?

EDIT: 
Load balancer and Target Group config -

```
resource "aws_alb" "alb" {
  name            = "${var.alb_name}"
  subnets         = flatten(["${var.public_subnet_ids}"])
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.alb.id}"]

  access_logs {
    bucket  = "${aws_s3_bucket.alb-logs.bucket}"
    prefix  = "load-balancer-logs"
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "lb_target_group_app" {
  name                 = "${var.alb_name}-default"
  /* port                 = 5555 */  /* DAMEON health check port */
  port                 = 5000 .   /* Application health check port */
  protocol             = "HTTP"
  vpc_id               = "${var.vpc_id}"
  deregistration_delay = "${var.deregistration_delay}"

  health_check {
    path     = "${var.health_check_path}"
    port = "5000"        /* Is this needed here ?  */
    interval = "300"
    timeout = "120"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  depends_on = ["aws_alb.alb"]
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "https_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_alb.alb.id}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate.ssl_cert.arn}"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.lb_target_group_app.arn}"
    type             = "forward"
  }
}

Container definition for dameon - 

  container_definitions = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "${var.environment}-${var.datadog-identifier}",
    "image": "datadog/agent:latest",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 8126,
        "hostPort": 8126,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "containerPort": 5555,
        "hostPort": 5555,
        "protocol": "TCP"
      },
      {
        "containerPort": 8125,
        "hostPort": 8125,
        "protocol": "UDP"
      }
    ],
    "environment": [
      { "name" : "DD_API_KEY", "value" : "xxxxxxxxx" },
      { "name" : "DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC", "value" : "true" },
      { "name" : "DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC", "value" : "true" },
      { "name": "DD_LOG_LEVEL", "value": "trace" },
      { "name": "DD_SITE", "value": "datadoghq.com" },
      { "name": "DD_HEALTH_PORT", "value": "5555" },
      { "name" : "DD_PROCESS_AGENT_ENABLED", "value" : "true" },
      { "name" : "DD_LOGS_ENABLED", "value" : "true" },
      { "name" : "DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL", "value" : "true" },
      { "name" : "DD_APM_ENABLED", "value" : "true" }
    ],

Container definition for app - 

    container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
[
  {
    "name": "app",
    "image": "quay.io/xxxxxxxx",
    "essential": true,
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/ec2/service/${var.cluster}",
        "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ec2"
      }
    },
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "APP_ENV",
        "value": "localhost"
      },
      {
        "name": "AUTH_JWT_SECRET",
        "value": "xxxxxxxx"
      }
    ],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 5000,
        "hostPort": 5000,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],

Service definition for dameon task - 
resource "aws_ecs_service" "datadog" {
  name            = "${var.environment}-${var.datadog-identifier}-datadog-ecs-service"
  cluster         = "${var.cluster}"
  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.datadog.arn}"


  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = "${element(var.default_alb_target_group,0)}"
    container_name   = "${var.environment}-${var.datadog-identifier}"
    container_port   = 5555 .   /* datadog health check port */
  }
  # This allows running one for every instance
  scheduling_strategy = "DAEMON"
}



Service definition for app task - 
resource "aws_ecs_service" "app-service" {
        name            = "app-service"
        cluster         = "${var.cluster}"
        task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.app.arn}"
        desired_count   = 2
        launch_type    = "EC2"

        load_balancer {
          target_group_arn  = "${element(var.default_alb_target_group,0)}"
          container_port    = 5000  /* app port exposed here */
          container_name    = "pared-somm"
        }
```

The way to reproduce this would be to -

```
1. Create ALB as below
2. Create 1 Target Group as below with a port to listen on. Add health check block to the Target Group (is port needed here or should I use Traffic port instead ?)
3. Create 2 tasks and service definitions (container definitions below) both pointing to the load balancer above. So when the tasks start running, they both run on the same targets in the above target group. 
4. Check the Targets and their health and you should see 2 entries per target.
```

Comment: How are you configuring your load balancers, target groups and health checks? Can you edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I added the ALB and Target group configuration. I can also add the seperate task and service definitions for both the daemon and application if you think that might help.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I went ahead and added the container definitions for the 2 tasks. Let me know if you need anything else.